# How to migrate Log4j Filter to Log4j 2

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I got a Java Webapplication that starts an asynchron server side "job".
The application creates a directory for each job and logs in a file in this directory.

My implementation with log4j is:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;
public class ThreadLogger {

  String sThreadName;
  String sLogfilePath;

  RollingFileAppender rfaJob;
  PatternLayout plJobLog;

  public ThreadLogger(){}

  public void start(String sThreadId, String sLogfilePath){

      this.sThreadName = sThreadId;
      this.sLogfilePath = sLogfilePath;

      // Create Logfilter and LogAppender for thread based logging
      ThreadLoggingFilter ThreadLogFilter = new ThreadLoggingFilter(this.sThreadName);

      plJobLog = new PatternLayout("[%x - %t][%d / %p / %c] - %m%n");

      this.rfaJob = new RollingFileAppender();
      this.rfaJob.setLayout(plJobLog);
      this.rfaJob.setFile(sLogfilePath);
      this.rfaJob.setEncoding("UTF-8");
      this.rfaJob.activateOptions();
      this.rfaJob.setMaxBackupIndex(9);
      this.rfaJob.setMaxFileSize("10MB");
      this.rfaJob.setThreshold(Level.ALL);
      this.rfaJob.addFilter(ThreadLogFilter);

      Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(this.rfaJob);   
  }

  public void stop(){
      Logger.getRootLogger().removeAppender(this.rfaJob);
      this.rfaJob.close();
  }

}
```

and the ThreadLogginFilter is:

```
import org.apache.log4j.spi.*;


public class ThreadLoggingFilter extends Filter {
  String threadName;

  public ThreadLoggingFilter(String _threadName){
      this.threadName = _threadName;
  }

  @Override
  public int decide(final LoggingEvent event) {
      if (event.getNDC() != null && event.getNDC().equals(this.threadName)) {
          return ACCEPT;
      }
      return DENY;
  }
}
```

No I want to implement this with log4j2 and don´t know how to do the filter.

I know the documentation on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html but I cant find a way to do this.
Is it possible to do this without a configuration?

**Update: The goal...**
My webapplication starts threads. Every thread produces several files to a folder that will be send to the user at the end. Within the folder there has to be the log file. So every thread need his own appender with a foldername.

Comment: have you read the documentation here [https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html] ? See the section filters

Comment: There are several ways to implement it and I'm not sure of the best approach for you. 1. Why do you need to programmatically add the Appender and Filter? 2. Are you really wanting a new configuration as shown at https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-samples/configuration/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/configuration/CustomConfiguration.java or are you trying to add on to an existing configuration? With Log4j 2 the Thread name is in the LogEvent so your filter doesn't need to get if from the NDC. It is always best to explain what the end result you need is.

Comment: @rogers: Thank you for your questions. I will update my question with the needed result.